# "Who Bought This Item Also Bought" type of recommendation with matrix factorization

Tags: collaborative-filtering

I know that it is possible to do "Who Bought This Item Also Bought" type of recommendation using item-based collaborative filtering. My question is how we can do this using matrix factorization (MF). One possible solution might be to learn item features with MF and then calculate the similarities of items based on these features. But this is not "pure MF", I mean, in the end I still need to calculate the similarities between all pairs of item features which takes $O(n^2)$ time. Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to your question instead another question for you. You mentioned "it is possible to do "Who Bought This Item Also Bought" type of recommendation using item-based collaborative filtering", can you recommend me some source links?

Comment: since you already find similarities between items you can just sort them for an item.